# How to use WeasyPrint PDF Builder on Password Protected Pages?

Tags: python, flask, weasyprint

I'm trying to download a page from my Flask app using WeasyPrint but when downloading the PDF, I'm getting the login page as the PDF rather than the expected page.

I'm using the following code:

```
@app.route('/report.pdf')
def hello_pdf():
    # Make a PDF from another view
    return render_pdf(url_for('myprojects'))
```

The login decorator is:

```
def login_required(f):
    '''login required decorator to protect routes
    '''
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap
```

For some reason, the function can't seem to download the protected view, despite me being logged in. How can I get it to download it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `render_template` just returns a html string, so I can do the following at the end of a route:

```
html = render_template('myprojects.html', projects=projects)
return render_pdf(HTML(string=html))
```